# With Truesight do you know that a creature is invisible?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, invisibility

Would a creature with Truesight know that the creature they are seeing is Invisible?

I noticed that the See Invisibility spell says "you see invisible creatures and objects as if they were visible" PHB 274. This seems to suggest that everything appears completely normal.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Yes

Truesight specifies (PHB, 284). Emphasis is mine.

> A creature with truesight can...**automatically detect visual illusions** and succeed on saving throws against them, and perceives the original form of a shapechanger or a **creature that is transformed by magic**. Furthermore, the creature can see into the Ethereal plane.

Invisibility is an Illusion spell(PHB, 254), and Truesight automatically detects visual illusions and gives you perception of a creature trasnformed by magic. Therefore, you not only see them, but you've detected the illusion of invisibility or seen the original form of a creature that uses magic of any sort to make them invisible.

### For See Invisibility, The rest of the party may also have input

The language remains a bit of an issue for See Invisibility, but as long as there is one more person available to ask 'Hey, you see this?", then they'll confirm the creature is invisible.

Comment: I think you could edit your answer even further. The description you've quoted says that the truesight both "detects visual illusions" and "perceives the original form of a creature transformed by magic". So your answer shows that the creature with truesight will both be able to see the invisible person, but also see the spell around it that made them invisible.

Comment: Some creatures are natively invisible....such as an Invisible Stalker. This is not necessarily the work of an illusion.

Comment: @as.beaulieu great point! Updated my answer.

Comment: @guildsbounty The invisible stalker is "an air elemental" that has been "transformed by powerful magic." I'd say that makes it's invisibility magical.

Comment: You should add a link to the JC's tweet - https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/786003400517300224 where he says that "Truesight pierces invisibility"